# Android:Action Bar Styling

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make action bar something like the image and I dont have any clue how can I do it. Any help in making this type of action bar would be great especially the part where the title of activity is along with the background

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the title to be your own custom image you can set a custom layout,

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_title_layout);
```

Where R.layout.my_title_layout is the layout for your title with the background and text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="22sp" 
    android:background="@drawable/title_background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will have it centered, you can set the background through a shape drawable which I have named title_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/pink"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/pink" />
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

For setting the font you would need a custom view or inflate the layout.

Comment: i couldn't understand "title to be your own custom image you can set a custom view" and how do i place it in the centre of action bar ?

Comment: I'll write an example one sec

Comment: it is not working.. see this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486151/android-unable-to-style-action-bar