# Android: Unable to style action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to get something like this [image]

for this I have written title_layout which looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp" 
        android:background="@drawable/background"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and background.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <solid android:color="@color/pink"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/pink" />
    <corners android:radius="20dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />

</shape>
```

and I have overriden onCreateOptionsMenu method as

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.title_layout);
        return true;
    }
```

UI looks the same even if I dont write any of the code.

Comment: [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in your onCreate():

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.title_layout);
```

That should work